# From another class, how do I call a method that's declared in the implementation file but not interface?

Tags: objective-c

In this tutorial here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/62989/introduction-c-ios-developers-part-1

It mentions that for Objective-C:

> Even if you only declare a method inside the implementation of a
>   class, and don’t expose it in the interface, you technically could
>   still call that method externally.

How is this done?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways.

For example, as long as a compatible method is declared *somewhere*, you can call it normally with dynamic typing. Here's a demonstration:

```
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@end

// MyClass.m
@interface MyClass()
- (void)addObject;
@end
@implementation MyClass
- (void)addObject:(id)object {
    NSLog(@"Whoa, I got called!");
}
@end

// main.m
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyClass.h"

int main() {
    id something = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    [something addObject:@"Look ma, no errors!"];
    return 0;
}
```

Since there is a known method named `addObject:` that takes an object, and `id` variables are dynamically typed, this is 100% valid and will call MyClass's `addObject:` method.

They could even get it with a statically typed variable and a method that isn't known by declaring the method in a category. A few other options:

- using `performSelector:` as @michaels showed in his answer
- going straight to `objc_msgSend()`
- getting the method IMP and calling it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `performSelector:` method of [NSObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html), though the compiler will give you a warning if the selector is not publicly declared anywhere

```
[someObject performSelector:@selector(someMethod)];
```